# LibGDX antialiasing

Tags: java, libgdx, antialiasing

Is there a way to implement antialiasing in LibGDX?

My lines are very pixilated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you tried this link? http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2071

Comment: Wow, this link is verry helpful.

Comment: this link is dead :-(

Comment: @Sebastian You can use the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20200427101053/https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2071

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To smooth any line or shape use multi sampling anti aliasing 
**replace:**
`Gdx.gl.glclear()` 
**with:** 
`Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | (Gdx.graphics.getBufferFormat().coverageSampling?GL20.GL_COVERAGE_BUFFER_BIT_NV:0))`

and for Android, open AndroidLauncher.java file and put : `config.numSamples = 2` **2** is a good value

for desktops`config.samples=3` this will do your work...

Comment: @SamanMiran nope, see Manuel's downvoted answer below for better interpolation of textures. This is only fixes the edges of textures (which i advise you to leave transparent whenever possible)

Comment: If you're using Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration, then you won't be able to access the samples field. Instead do "config.setBackBufferConfig(8,8,8,8,16,0,num_of_samples);". These values are the defaults - only set the last parameter which is the samples value.

Answer (score 3):

You can also put the filter in the texture itself

```
bg = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("data/bg.png")));
//bg.getTexture().setFilter(GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);
bg.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Comment: That is not the same thing as Anti aliasing plus he is not even using textures.

Answer (score 2):

Set the number of samples in your Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration. It defaults to 0, try something higher:

```
final Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
int samples = 2; // you can also play around with hiher values like 4
config.setBackBufferConfig(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0, samples); // 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0 are default values
```